# agent++ and nagios

Tags: snmp, nagios

I have agent++ (www.agentpp.com) installed on all systems at a client site running our proprietary app on Ubuntu linux. I want to monitor these systems from a central server running nagios. Is there code available in agent++ examples that would enable me to send information such as number of processes, number of users, disk usage etc  of the monitored system to the central nagios server using agent++? If so, can you please point me to it? If not, is it possible to do so and how can I do it?

Appreciate any help and pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try `NRPE`, there is lots of script already available out there

Answer (score 0):

Me to suggest NRPE(Nagios Remote Plug in Extractor )

Refer the below site for the STEPS

http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-add-linux-host-to-nagios-monitoring-server/

Comment: NSclient is also good, but i had used it only for windows machines, there its awesome